# Value of type 'Character' has no member 'isUppercase'

Tags: ios, swift, character

I am running my Xcode project on the other computer as usual. And when I tried to build my project, I keep getting an error on the Character type. The variable isNumber, isUppercase, isLowercase, isPunctuation, isSymbol, isCurrencySymbol are not working. Xcode always gives me an error like this :

> Value of type 'Character' has no member 'isCurrencySymbol'

I looked up on the web but no one seems to ever had this error. Here is my code.

```
    func containsNumber() -> Bool {
        var result = false
        for char in self {
            if char.isNumber {
                result = true
            }
        }
        return result
    }

    func containsCapital() -> Bool {
        var result = false
        for char in self {
            if char.isUppercase {
                result = true
            }
        }
        return result
    }
    func containsLowercase() ->  Bool {
        var result = false
        for char in self {
            if char.isLowercase {
                result = true
            }
        }
        return result
    }

    func containsSpecialCharacters() -> Bool {
        var result = false
        for char in self {
            if char.isPunctuation {
                result = true
            }
            if char.isSymbol {
                result = true
            }
            if char.isCurrencySymbol {
                result = true
            }
        }
        return result
    }

    func containsEnoughCharacter(numberOfCharacters : Int) -> Bool {
        var result = false
        if self.count >= numberOfCharacters {
            result = true
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me why I keep getting this kind of error, because when I look upon apple doc those variable exist.

Comment: Where are these functions defined ? Are they in string Extension ?

Comment: add some additional code, where u called this, for e.g "containsLowercase"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting this error `Value of type 'Character' has no member 'isCurrencySymbol'` then it is very likely your XCode is lesser than version **10.2**

Check your XCode version. If it is less than 10.2 you'll get this error and you need to upgrade your XCode.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is it

Comment: @MathiasErligmann please accept the answer if it is the correct solution

Comment: I did, but I can't upvote it yet because I below 15